# How to get SQL in query result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Now, there is a table [A] which has a column `[A].[Sql](NVARCHAR)` stored all the filter for

> table [B] conditions like " 1=1 AND Id='XXX' AND Key = 'YYYY'"

Now, What I want to do is query on table [B] and use [A].sql value as WHERE condition, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [B] 
WHERE "SELECT [A].sql From [A] WHERE [B].ConditionId = [A].Id"
```

1. How to write such T-SQL?
2. Is it possible to make a string to be part of SQL?

Comment: use sp_executesql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1) sp_executesql function
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

or

2) Exec function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL. Basically you generate a varchar with the SQL you need, then you execute it with a `EXEC`, like the following:

```
DECLARE @FilterCondition VARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (SELECT [A].sql From [A] WHERE [B].ConditionId = [A].Id)

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM [B] WHERE ' + @FilterCondition

-- PRINT (@DynamicSQL)

EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

Please note that executing dynamic SQL is very risky and you need to validate the command to execute before executing it. For a disastrous example, what would happen if the `@FilterCondition` has the following?

```
1 = 0; DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(30) = DB_NAME(); EXEC ('DROP DATABASE ' + @DBName);
```

Comment: Great help! Thanks for your advice.